# If {|$b_n$|} converges, then does {$b_n$} converge? Explain

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

How do I start this? Do I state what $\epsilon$ is and follow the convergence definition?

Answer (score 5):

No. Here is a counterexample: $b_n=(-1)^n$.